# Passing userform as an argument from word vba to vb.net

Tags: vba

I am trying to migrate parts of a system that handles word templates. Until now, common functionality has been spread out on several .dots (with vba) on a fileserver. We are now aiming at putting this functionality into a vb.net application which we interact with as a reference from word.

I would like to call vb.net functionality from vba, passing a userform as an argument. 
From a form test class in vb.net it works fine with TestFunction(inForm:=Me).
From vba I have tried all sorts of calls, none of which I have gotten to work.

**.net function I am trying to call**

`Public Sub TestFunction(ByVal inForm As Form)
      'do something...

    End Sub`

**call from word vba**

`Public sReference As MyNetApp.DocFunc`

```
Set sReference = CreateObject("MyNetApp.DocFunc")
sReference.TestFunction(frmMyForm)
```

Reference to .net set up according to: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html and works fine with other functionality, just the forms that I cannot figure out how to handle.

So, my question is how I pass the form? And is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is possible or not, but do you really need to do that?  If you just need data on the form then just pass the data.